# Creating hyper Tableau Extract in Python 3

Tags: python, tableau-api

I want to create a tableau extract off of a data frame that I created in Jupyter Lab (Python3).

I installed the Extract API 2.0 from tableau. However, when i'm trying to run the code I'm getting this error message:

TableauException: TableauException (300): CreateProcess(...,lpCommandLine=""C:\Users\MyUserName\tableausdk\bin\hyper\hyperdstarter.exe" --init "overwrite" --skip-license --no-password --no-ssl --init-user "tableau_internal_user" -x "persist_redo_log=false" --log-dir "C:\Users\MyUserName" -x "log_config=file,json,all,DataExtract_G6vnJNuJ,0" --database "C:\Users\MyUserName\hyper_db_G6vnJNuJ" --listen-connection "tab.pipe://./pipe/auto" --callback-connection "tab.pipe://./pipe/{20C7AA69-1A15-4139-A96F-BFF153B82ABE}" run",...): Win32 error: 1260

## This is the code I'm using in Jypyter

from tableausdk import *
from tableausdk.HyperExtract import *

ExtractAPI.initialize()
new_extract = Extract('Test1.hyper')

Answer (score 1):

It appears Windows is preventing hyperdstarter.exe from starting due to:

> Error 1260: Windows cannot open this program because it has been
>   prevented by a software restriction policy. For more information, open
>   Event Viewer or contact your system administrator.

Look in the Windows Event Log and you should find a log message giving more details. Searching the Internet shows this could happen after a certain Windows update happen, see [Microsoft TechNet article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/44d5f8a2-fdef-4fd9-b1e3-af3fa6181779/error-1260-windows-cannot-open-this-program-because-it-has-been-prevented-by-a-software-restriction?forum=winservergen). If your machine is on a corporate network and joined to a domain, it could be a restrictive group policy that is causing this too.